# How can I return the result of a "GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet" query after it finishes execution (Swift using Sheets API)?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create an inventory management app for iOS using Swift and the Google Sheets API. Before starting that, I want to get acquainted with the API and make sure everything works properly. To do that, I want to create a function getCell that returns the contents of a cell at a hardcoded row and column (given in A1 notation as required). Since the Sheets API's implementation in Swift seems to require a callback model (I'm a beginner on callbacks and async programming in general), **I haven't figured out how to return the cell's contents in my function after the query finishes.**

I've followed the Sheets API iOS Quickstart provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift&hl=zh-cn) to enable the API in the Developers Console and install the necessary Cocoapods (my Podfile installs 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets' and 'GoogleSignIn'). I got the included code to run and work properly after converting some parts to newer Swift syntax.

The issue arose when I wrote my getCell function in the ViewController.swift file. As can be seen in the code below, I assumed that the query would finish by the time getCellQuery finishes, so that getCell would be able to access the global variable updated by the callback function (displayResultWithTicket). However, the debug print statements I put in show that the callback function only executes at the end of the program, after getCell checks the global variable and finds nothing new. Note that the spreadsheet ID needs to be replaced with a real one to run this code.

```
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GoogleSignIn
import UIKit

struct MyVariables {
    static var currentCell: String? = nil
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]
    private let service = GTLRSheetsService()

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.service.authorizer = nil
        } else {
            self.signInButton.isHidden = true
            self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

            //main program starts here
            print("Cell: " + getCell(a1: "Inventory!A1"))
        }
    }

    func getCell(a1: String) -> String {
        print("Started getCell")
        getCellQuery(a1: a1)
        if MyVariables.currentCell != nil {
            print("Finished getCell")
            return MyVariables.currentCell!
        } else {
            print("Error: the global variable is nil and probably hasn't been changed")
            print("Finished getCell")
            return ""
        }
    }

    func getCellQuery(a1: String) {
        print("Started getCellQuery")
        let spreadsheetId = "INSERT ID HERE"

        // arbitrary row and column in A1 notation
        let getRange = a1
        let getQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet.query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:getRange)
        service.executeQuery(getQuery, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
        print("Finished getCellQuery")
    }

    @objc func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                                       finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_ValueRange,
                                       error : NSError?) {
        print("Started callback")
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // turn 2d array into string
        let rows = result.values!
        for row in rows {
            for item in row {
                // update global variable
                MyVariables.currentCell = item as? String
            }
        }
        print("Finished callback")
    }
}
```

After signing in, I would expect the following in the console:

> ```
> Started getCell
> Started getCellQuery
> Started callback
> Finished callback
> Finished getCellQuery
> Finished getCell
> Cell: <Whatever the cell has>
> ```

Instead, I get this:

> ```
> Started getCell
> Started getCellQuery
> Finished getCellQuery
> Error: the cell value is nil and probably hasn't been changed
> Finished getCell
> Cell: 
> Started callback
> Finished callback
> ```

Separately, I've also tried using a while loop to wait for the global variable to be updated, but it seems like Swift is consistently opting to call the callback function at the end of the entire program, which is annoying.

If there's a less clunky approach for this simple task, it would be great to know.

Comment: Any solution eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is with async calling patterns. When you call service.executeQuery, it will begin an async query but since it is hitting a web service, that query could take a long time to complete. The executeQuery function returns immediately and the query itself is probably queued by their library. At the next opportunity, the request is sent and when the reply comes back, your displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:) callback is called but in the meantime, the rest of your getCellQuery function completed, as did getCell.

A better pattern would be to fire some [notification](https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/notification-in-swift-d47f641282fa) event in the callback now that you have a response (and pass the value you got back in the notification) and then have a listener for that notification get the response and do the appropriate thing with the result.

Alternatively, there may be a method in the sheets API to pass in a [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) which is a lot like a callback but the code for it lives within the function that is passing it so state management is a little easier. I'm not familiar with that API so I'm not sure if that exists.

Here is an article on [managing async code](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f) in Swift that covers some of the options.  It's a little old, but it covers the basics.